# Radio button select one at a time using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, radio-button

I am facing problem with radio select button. I want to get the one checkbox selected at one time.

I am using the following scripts

paid radio button is created to submit the form automatically which submit the form very successfully.

and colorRadio with value red is created to open a right side div at the same page

now problem is this one checkbox should be selected but it selected the two radio button

and when I keep the same name paid then it does not work

otherwise code is works fine which I wanted to perform is working fine 
but only one checkbox should be selected at a one time

any help will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'     
src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() { 
$('input[name=paid]').change(function(){

    $('form').submit();

});
});

</script>






 <div align="left"><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"><img src="visa/ff.jpg"></div>
 <br>

 <div align="left"><input type="radio" name="paid" value="paid"><br>
```

Comment: Where is checkbox? Post your html with checkboxes correctly

Answer (score 0):

try to change script:-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input[name=paid]').change(function(){
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Form:-

```
<form id='myform'>
<div align="left"><input type="radio" name="paid" value="red"><img src="visa/ff.jpg"></div> <br>
 <div align="left"><input type="radio" name="paid" value="paid"><br>
<br>
<img src="visa/1.gif"></div>
</form>
```